# how to install the latest gcc compiler from source on linux without messing everything else up?

Tags: linux, gcc

Hi is there an appropriate guide or tip or tricks to install gcc on a linux system such as red hat without using the package manager , from source , and with out having it mess everything else up? So that you can still use the previous compiler and switch back and forth easily?

Comment: For which Linux distribution or package manager?

Comment: updated the question a bit for you @fideli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't change any settings, it should be fine. It will install to `/usr/local`, which will keep it separate from that platform's default gcc installation.

You may want to give the configuration tool a "program suffix" option to give it a name based on the version.

I would start by doing a `gcc -v` to see what options your platform's default GCC build uses, and consider each of those options to see if you want to include them. Do not change any of the default directories as your platform default did though. You want it to go into `/usr/local`.

Comment: so i change `../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info`                                                                        to --prefix=usr/local  ?

Comment: You don't need to, `/usr/local` is the default.